# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined when using $http

Tags: angularjs

I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.getChannelIdFromYoutubeUsername
    at Object.vm.creatorAccountCreationFormSubmit
```

Even though I am injecting $http into my service, and whenever I paste the url being passed into the $http.get command, I get an output in my browser window.

Here is my service:

```
angular.module('adsomaApp').service('YoutubeService', function($log) {

  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3';

  function getChannelIdFromYoutubeUsername(youtubeApi, youtubeUsername, $http) {
    var queryUrl = url + "/channels/?key=" + youtubeApi + "&forUsername=" + youtubeUsername + "&part=id";
    return ($http.get(queryUrl).then(handleSuccess, handleError));
  }

  function handleSuccess(response) {
    return response.data;
  }

  function handleError(response) {
    if (!angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message) {
      return ($q.reject('An unknown error occurred.'));
    }
    return ($q.reject(response.data.message));
  }

  var youtubeService = {
    getChannelIdFromYoutubeUsername: getChannelIdFromYoutubeUsername
  };
  return youtubeService;
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
vm.channelId = {};

vm.creatorAccountCreationFormSubmit = function() {
  YoutubeService.getChannelIdFromYoutubeUsername(ConstantsService.youtubeSettings().youtubeApiKey, vm.connectYoutubeFormData.youtubeUsername).then(function(succ) {
    vm.channelId = succ;
    $log.info(vm.channelId);
  }, function error(err) {
    $log.error('Error: ', err);
  });
};
```

Comment: inject `$http` in your service `function($log, $http)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module('adsomaApp').service('YoutubeService', function($log, $http) { }
```

you didn't inject in service layer so it is showing undefin

Comment: Thanks - silly mistake.

Comment: sometimes errors are good for refreshing the knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1):

Two basic changes:

Inject $http into the Service

```
angular.module('adsomaApp').service('YoutubeService', function($http, $log) {
```

Remove $http from the arguments of this service method

```
function getChannelIdFromYoutubeUsername(youtubeApi, youtubeUsername) {
```

The issue is that, when this Service Method is being called from the Controller, the third argument is NOT sent by you. Which, basically means, $http will be null. 
I have addressed this issue by injecting $http in the service and by excluding the third argument in the method signature.

These two changes should take care of the issue. I have not included rest of the code.